# jQuery or Ajax gauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a gauge with multiple concentric circles, each circle showing values of different entities. Something like this...(see image)

Here each needle shows value of corresponding entity. I saw some gauges in jQuery & Ajax. So I was wondering if I could find something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider [Perfect Widgets](http://perfectwidgets.com) library. Please have a look at the [demo](http://perpetuumsoft.com/demo/pw/so-gauge-1/) I've created for you. I suppose it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

With knob plugin, you'll be able to perform what you want: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/
Just superpose plural input with a larger circumference each time and play with z-index.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at highcharts:

Demo with two Axis: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-dual

Demo with three "needles": http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-clock

Demo with two gauges: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-vu-meter

Answer (score 0):

You can try jqChart radial gauge - http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/RadialGauge/NestedScales

Here is a multiple needles example - http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/RadialGauge/Needles

And just an ordinary analog clock - http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/

Disclaimer: I work for jqChart.